# Javascript search file on server

Tags: javascript, css, regex

How can I get a filename in the directory where my site is stored using a regex?

For example:

```
/index.html
/resources/css/wp-guid.css
/resources/css/ios-guid.css
/resources/css/android-guid.css
```

1. The guid can change to values I do not know.
2. I know the files are stores in `/resources/css`
3. I know the css file begin with wp-*, ios-*, android-*
4. It's a webapp executed locally on mobile devices, no server logic can be applied.

How can I find out the real name of this files and store them to a var?

Comment: Without having access to server side code, you simply cannot. If javascript could scan servers to see which files they had available without the explicit functionality being provided by the server, this would have extreme security implications.

Comment: As James mentions about, this can only be done through code running on the server. JS running in a browser, by design, has no access to the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The act of scanning servers for files that are not explicitly linked to is a type of security exploit that gives attackers access to hidden files.

Therefore, there is no way to do this using client technologies alone.  However, I would recommend the following...

Whichever program you have that is changing the `guid` should also write the `guid` to a file called `latestGuid.txt`.  You can then use javascript to query `latestGuid.txt` and recreate the file names using the guid that is provided in that file.

The code that does this might look something like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "resources/latestGuid.txt", false);
xhr.send();
var guid = xhr.responseText;
```

Hope this helps.